# how to change jquery.mmenu width

Tags: jquery, mmenu

I have a problem. I want to change the width jquery.mmenu. 
When I change the width, a white space appears between the navbar and the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUUTc.jpg)sidebar.
How can I change the width so that this space does not appear

Comment: This question already has an answer. Check Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363523/mmenu-custom-width-settings

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!!

Comment: No issues. Kindly try to search similar questions before posting. Otherwise, it will effect your rating. Just a suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("target").css("width", "10px");
```

But i don't understand what you changed

Comment: you changed only the top div's width?